# Availability option when submitting an app to apple store

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, translation, availability

i have an app rejected by apple, because it is a translated version of one of my existing app. i asked him about playing with the availability, so that i will make the exiting app available in some countries, and the translated app on different countries.

i got the below feedback but still not clear, what do you understand from it?

"The application would be appropriate to have the availability revised for the application.the application should either only have one version for sale with localizations for each language or revised the availability for sale"

Comment: Create a single version of your app that includes localisations if required. You can use store availability to limit in which stores the app is available if required. So you can use either approach or both combined but you should only have a single app.

Comment: why it looks like i have more options "should either only have one version for sale with localizations for each language or revised the availability for sale"

Comment: I don't know, the reply is a little confusing, but I know that Apple doesn't want there to be multiple versions of essentially the same app in the store

Comment: many thanks Sir... i believe i should ask them again for more clarifications

Comment: I know how localization is working, but do you know how i can change the name of my app based on the store?

Comment: You can't change the name per store, you can only localise the App Store information, so the name will be reflected based on the person's locale (which will typically match the App Store country), but if someone in the French store has selected English locale, they will see the English name.